# Getting 2.4" SPI TFT LCD working with Beaglebone Black

Tags: spi, beagleboneblack, lcd, adafruit

What Kernel Fragment needs to be enabled.
Changes needed to Beaglebone Black Devicetree to enable SPI and adding drivier for TFT LCD
The physical connection details to get board up and running

Kernel Fragment for FB_TFT and Devicetree changes

Answer (score 1):

## Background

Wanted to explore the SPI-TFT-LCD available at cheape price. Here is the link for the LCD i used [Adafruit-2.4"-SPI-TFT-LCD](https://robu.in/product/2-4-inch-spi-interface-240x320-touch-screen-tft-display-module/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_O2lBhCFARIsAB0E8B-lpI-EShCc_62zLCbE5timLx2TejNSr-xE-1qm1t9QDtDFCTCqGtwaAkuwEALw_wcB)

## Connections with BBB

[Connection-Details-With-BBB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jixDn.png)

## Kernel fragment to add

[fragment-to-add-to-append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVrtC.png)

## Devicetree Updates

[DTS-Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MECsd.png) [DTS-Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAj7z.png)
**Note : Its mandatory to have backlight node, even if we are directly connecting LED to +3.3, without this node things wont work. Plus buswidth needs to be set to <8>, this did the trick for me, all the while i had this 9 considering the data sheet of LCD which suggested this as 4-wire, 9bit.**

## Update to bbappend in my-layer

- meta-mylayer/recipe-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_5.4.bbappend
  -> I am using poky-dunfell for my builds
  [bbpappend-changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSVeu.png)

## Finally loading the image and fb_ili9341.ko module

[console-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tPIP.png)

## Outcome

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cFPV.png)

Comment: Read comments to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755956/banana-pi-zero-p2-with-spi-display.